# How to hide layout when clicking the are outside it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout which has two child Relative Layouts.Lets call them rel1 and rel2. 
Rel1 has one title at the top . then a profile picture in the center . and two horizontally placed buttons at the bottom .

Rel2 has one listview .
Rel2 is aligned at the bottom of the parent layout . Rel2 takes 50% of the screen and initially its not visible .
When i click on one of the buttons in rel1 the rel2 becomes visible . 
Since rel2 takes half of the screen so , upper half of rel1 is visible and lower half of rel1 gets covered by rel2 .

My requirement is that when i click the upper half of the rel1 (which is not covered by rel2) , rel2 should hide.

How do i do this . should i add onclick listener on rel1 layout . If i add onclick on rel1 , what will happen when i click the children of rel1 layout . will the click event go to its children or the rel1 ..

Please help.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="23dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/center_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/Image"
            android:contentDescription="center IMage" />

            <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_avoid_warning"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button2"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_avoid_warning"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="7dp"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">
            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use a match_parent view behind it and add click listener to it :)

Comment: I am also thinking about adding a match parent transparent layout say rel3 , and make it visible when rel2 becomes visible other wise gone and adding onclick listener on that .  Just not sure if its a good idea , i mean its just hack. i wanted to know if i can find any better solution

Comment: There are creepy solutions like adding a touchlistener on all view and listen to it. But the invisible layout is pretty neat. Or you should show the layout in dialog

Comment: if you have onclick listener on both parent and child views then OS will take care of click event. First it will check for the child click listener based on the area you have clicked if it there then child click will happen(in this case it will not search for parent click). If child click is not there then it will check for parent click listener

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan thanks . It helped . I am adding the transparent layout for click event . Its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try This it may be help to you

```
private RelativeLayout llRoot;
private RelativeLayout llContent;

llRoot = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel1);//in onCreate()
llContent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel2);//in onCreate()

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect ContentBounds = new Rect();
    llRoot.getHitRect(ContentBounds);

    if (ContentBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
        //Do Your stuff here

    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make both rel1 and rel2 clickable adding `android:clickable="true"` and then add an `OnClickListener` to rel1.

Comment: But if i add onclick on rel1 and then if the click any child(all children are clickable) inside rel1 , then will the click event go to both rel1 and the child clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="23dp"
        android:onClick="hideMe"
        android:clickable=true
        android:paddingTop="12dp" >


 public void hideMe(View view){
 ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rel2, null);
 viewgroup.setVisibility(View,GONE);//CHECK THE OTHER OPTION BELOW
 }
```

View.GONE 
-Everything is removed, Space is available for other widgets
View.INVISIBLE
-Everything will be removed but space is not available to other wigets

Comment: i do not get it . You want me to hide rel1 when i click on rel1 ??? 
I want to hide rel2 when i click on rel1

Answer (score 0):

make first `relativelayout` clickable and add `click listener` on first it will hide second

```
 Rel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {             
     if(Rel2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
        Rel2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } 
}
});
```